# What is an integrated circuit equivalent for this circuit?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I am trying to design a so called signal switch in which I can direct the signal to either go to NODE1 while NODE2 remains HIGH, or the signal goes to NODE2 and NODE1 remains HIGH. The following circuit with transistors seems to do its job in the simulation in Proteus, but I would like to implement it with some kind of integrated circuit. What IC could I use for this?[image]

EDIT: for clarification, the signal is digital, coming from node R13(1), the arrow-ish thing in the emitter of the transistors is a Power Rail in Proteus - the software that I have used for this circuit

Comment: Are the "arrows pointing up" supposed to be ground?  If so, they should always point downwards.  Otherwise it looks like an unlabeled power connection.

Comment: This question needs a ***lot*** of work.  "the signal" - Where?  There appear to be three inputs, but you do not identify any of them.  What type of signal is being "directed"?  What is the power source for the circuit?

Comment: You should just make a truth table. Still not clear on what you are actually doing.

Comment: The "arrows pointing up" are actually Power Rails (+5V ) - I am using Proteus.

Comment: The signal comes from the left, is digital and is represented by the trapezoid-shaped signal generator (in Proteus this is a Pulse Generator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What IC could I use for this?*

I would tend to choose analogue switches for replacing the BJTs and series resistors. I would use a normally closed analogue switch for the resistor and a normally open analogue switch for its associated BJT. Then, toggle the control line and the output becomes grounded (mimicking the BJT). Something like these would work OK: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/MAX4636.html). Each analogue switch shown above has a normally closed and normally open contact hence, one analogue switch element replaces the resistor and its associated BJT.

The devil will be in some of the detail and your question is rather lacking in detail so, choosing the "right" device may not be as simple as a walk in the park. Information lacking: -

- Power supply rails
- Signal levels
- Signal frequency range
- Is DC integrity important?
- Current (amps) throughput
- Leakage currents (maximums)
- Terminal capacitance
- "on" resistance
- "off" resistance
- Logic levels

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to mention that my signal is digital, in 5V logic, the power supply is at 5V, the maximum frequency is 38400 bps (so 38.4 kHz ), and I guess the current consumption is low, I have not tested it.

Comment: Then you can use logic gates or analogue switches/multiplexers then @Theodor

Comment: Yes, I will try working with a 74LS139 high speed Dual 1-of-4 Decoder/De-multiplexer

Answer (score 4):

If your input is a digital signal, the functionality you are describing is a simple 1-of-2 decoder/demultiplexer. These can be bought as simple logic ICs.

For example the [SN74LVC1G19](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g19.pdf) from TIs Little Logic series (other manufacturers have equivalents) has the following truth table:

[image: Truth table of 1G19 IC]

The output is selected by `A`, which will then follow the state of the `!E` signal, whilst the other output will remain high.

If your signal is Analogue, then @Andy's suggestion of an analogue switch is probably the best approach.

Comment: The signal is in 5V digital logic, I will try doing this with a multiplexer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an analog mux (multiplexer/demultiplexer).

The cheapest and most readily available are the 4052 like the [74HC(T)4052](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4052.pdf). They are designed for typical 5V usage (can go up to 10V) and are rated up to around 100 kHz.

[image: Functional diagram]

You may also find usage in 4051 and 4053 parts (other analog multiplexers, with different I/O configurations).

Comment: I will be using a common 1 to 2 demultiplexer such as 74HC(T)4052 or 74LS139.